# My Launch screen image has a wrong size on small screens

Tags: ios

I'm struggling with the size of a LaunchScreen storyboard image.

Basically, it is very small on iPhone 4s, while being OK on larger screens.

Here is the storyboard file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15703"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Llm-lL-Icb"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xb3-aO-Qok"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" image="Splash" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gsU-AJ-eSp">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="193" width="320" height="182"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" heightSizable="YES" widthSizable="YES"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="Splash" width="470" height="320"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Now displaying this storyboard in Xcode does show the differences that I'm viewing at runtime. The settings seems the same.

iPhone SE (2nd gen), Ok for Me.

[image]

iPhone 4s (too small)

[image]

What can be the source of the problem? Is it the image itself? I'm missing something here but cannot figure it out yet.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your UIImageView's leading, trailing, top, and bottom space constraints in your storyboard file:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

And then set your `UIImageView` content mode to `scaleAspectFit`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in imageView with constrains trailing and leading = 0 to the safe area, Top & Bottom = 0 to the superView, make Content mode = Scale to fill and I think It will work fine